# What is the interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{\log n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

I just wanted to ensure that my interval of convergence is correct: We have $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{\log n}.$$

My approach: I applied the ratio test and ended up with $x\cdot\log(n)/\log(n+1)$. Because the right fraction goes to $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity, the series converges absolutely for$ |x|< 1$. For $1$ and $-1$, I just plugged it into the series and concluded, that for $-1$ it converges and for $1$ it diverges. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Congrats! You have already answered the question correctly.

Comment: Just one nitpick, you should also say what happens for $|x| > 1$. But I'm sure you knew it already.